# Combining autoResizeRows and setting empty rows to a size of 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, autosize

My goal is to set empty rows to a hight of 1 and filled ones to a fitting size (autosized) but I cant find a way to combine those two.
This is, what I'm currently using but it sets empty rows to 21 instead of 1:

```
function Higth() { 
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

s.autoResizeRows(5, 31);
// 5 is the row in which the resizing starts and 31 is the amount of rows this is done
}
```

I hope someone knows a way to do this.

Jonah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the implementation in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618987/how-to-change-the-height-of-multiple-rows-at-once), given the active range:

> ```
> function changeRowHeight()
> {
>   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>   var sht=ss.getActiveSheet()
>   var rng=sht.getActiveRange();
>   var row=rng.getRow();
>   var numrows=rng.getNumRows();
>   var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Get Row Height', 'Enter Row Height in Pixels', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
>   var height = Number(resp.getResponseText());
>   for(var i=0;i<numrows;i++)
>   {
>     sht.setRowHeight(row + i, height)
>   }
> }
> ```

Then you can insert some `if()` statement to check if the given row is filled with text using the [`autoResizeRows`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeRows(Integer,Integer))function given in the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). It should be something like this:

> Sets the height of all rows starting at the given row position to fit
>   their contents.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
>
> // Sets the first 15 rows to a height that fits their text.
> sheet.autoResizeRows(1, 15);
> ```