# Google Sheets Script - Set a fixed height to rows (range as int)

Tags: google-sheets

I am unsuccessfully trying to reset my row heights on a regular basis to a certain value:

```js
function clearGuestlist() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("FormsGuestlist");
  var drucksheet = ss.getSheetByName("Druck");
  var tabletsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tablet");
  var druckrange = drucksheet.getRange('Druck!1:200');
  var tabletrange = tabletsheet.getRange('Tablet!1:200');

  first.clearContents();

  drucksheet.autoResizeRows(1, 200);
  tabletsheet.autoResizeRows(1, 200);

  drucksheet.setRowHeight(druckrange, 31);
  tabletsheet.setRowHeight(tabletrange, 31);
}
```

The `autoResizeRows` unfortunately doesn't work in my case so I would like to use the `setRowHeight`, but it wouldn't accept my range as it expects an int.
Any idea how I can tell it to resize all my rows?

Comment: Apparently, you have to set the range, iterate over it and set the row height along the way: Refer to @Cooper's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44619230/11832197)

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `The autoResizeRows unfortunately doesn't work in my case`?

Answer (score 1):

The `Range` class has a [`getRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow) method that you can use to retrieve the row position as an integer.

You can call this on the `druckrange` and `tabletrange` objects to get the position and then use [`setRowHeights()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightsstartrow,-numrows,-height) to set the height for your selected number of rows. Note that you have to use `setRowHeights()` instead of `setRowHeight()` because you have to plug in the start row and number of rows, like in `autoResizeRows()`, whereas `setRowHeight()` just takes the position of a single row.

Your code should look something like this:

```js
function clearGuestlist() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("FormsGuestlist");
  var drucksheet = ss.getSheetByName("Druck");
  var tabletsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tablet");
  var druckrange = drucksheet.getRange('Druck!1:200');
  var tabletrange = tabletsheet.getRange('Tablet!1:200');

  first.clearContents();

  drucksheet.setRowHeights(druckrange.getRow(), 200, 31); //gets the row position of druckrange as an int, then sets height to 31 pixels for 200 rows
  tabletsheet.setRowHeights(tabletrange.getRow(), 200, 31); //same as above for tabletrange
}
```